# Cannot set printer settings via ResetDc when doing the second time call to a dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a dll in which I have printing unit.

In my application I have exported methods to begin,end printing process as well as print documents.

The calls to a dll can be as follows:

```
1-> begin printing and print document
2-> print document
3-> end printing.
```

I am changing settings before each printed page (tray, orientation, etc)
Step 1 is done successfully
when I make another call (2) and try to change printer settings, method: ResetDc
for a dev mode structure returns false ...

Is it the problem that when I am back in app after 1 call, app printers unit changes something which prevents subsequent calls in a dll?

How to workaround the problem?

### EDIT

Here is the function which set page settings.
When 1 call is made (from the above list) ResetDC is executed successfully, but in the next call ResetDC returns false. Why ... ?

```
function PRPageSetup(paperSize: Integer = DMPAPER_A4): Boolean;
var
  pDevice: pChar;
  pDriver: pChar;
  pPort: pChar;
  hDMode: THandle;
  PDMode: PDEVMODE;
  PrnHandle: THandle;

begin
  result := false;
  GetMem(pDevice, cchDeviceName);
  GetMem(pDriver, MAX_PATH);
  GetMem(pPort, MAX_PATH);

  Printer.GetPrinter(pDevice, pDriver, pPort, hDMode);

  if hDMode <> 0 then
  begin
    pDMode := GlobalLock(hDMode);
    if pDMode <> nil then
    begin                 
         pDMode^.dmFields := pDMode^.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE or DM_ORIENTATION;
         pDMode^.dmPaperSize := paperSize;        

      if Printer.Printing then
        PrnHandle := printer.Canvas.Handle
       else
        PrnHandle := Printer.Handle;

      if ResetDc(PrnHandle, pDMode^) <> 0
        then PRCanReset := true
        else PRCanReset := false;

      Result := true;
      GlobalUnlock(hDMode);
    end;
  end;
  FreeMem(pDevice, cchDeviceName);
  FreeMem(pDriver, MAX_PATH);
  FreeMem(pPort, MAX_PATH);
end;
```

Comment: Show the declarations of those functions, both on DLL side and on eXE side. Don't put "like that" - show the real code instead. DLL are dangerous and fragile. You'd better use BPL instead.

Comment: @Arioch'The I have added some code

Comment: Is the printer printing or not when it fails? A DC is not interchangeable with a printer handle. `ResetDC` expects a DC..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz it fails during printing, I am ending the page and try to setup another one in the next dll call. Then it fails. What do you mean DC? (Furthermore when it fails, getlasterror returns 0 ...)

Comment: @John - By DC, I mean a device context. Printer.Canvas.Handle is a device context, it is fine for ResetDC. But you cannot pass a printer handle to ResetDC. Look at your code, there's an 'if' statement before you call it. If 'Printer.Printing' is returning false then you're passing a printer handle to ResetDC, it is wrong, it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve the problem.

I have discovered that I cannot setup thepage while TMetaFileCanvases where still in the memory. I needed to free them first and then reconfigure the page.

Thanks all for your effort and time.